# How to work with ENS without starting own node?

Tags: go-ethereum, infura, ens

I am trying to get how to work with ENS. It is relatively clear how it works, but most questionable thing for me is whether it possible to work with, for instance, Ropsten resolver without running my own node (ropsten database eats more then 40Gb for now)?

I am trying to get contract deployed [here](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x112234455c3a32fd11230c42e7bccd4a84e02010#code) via web3 and INFURA using `new web3.eth.contract(jsonInterface, address)` and it works but then all cals returns error `TypeError: contract.abi.filter is not a function`

Final question: how to test ENS without running local geth node?